# Custom archetypes for AngularJS (Dart)

Tags: angularjs, angular, dart, dart-pub

Is there something like Maven Archetypes for AngularJS (Dart)?

Update: I looked into Stagehand (as mentioned by **Günter Zöchbauer**), but it only supports standard templates. Unfortunately, I can't create my own templates.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking for. [Stagehand](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/stagehand) does something like that but doesn't support custom templates. There was another project that allowed to use a GitHub repo as template, but I haven't heard of that since a long time.

Comment: you can still fork stagehand and write your own templates if that's really what you want though.

Comment: I created a Github issue: https://github.com/google/stagehand/issues/394